# What credentials do you enter to use a network printer?

Tags: printing, networking

I've added a network printer. Both the host and guest are Ubuntu.

The printer added fine, but the system asks for authentication when I try to print. I typed the host's (the account that installed the printer) username/password, didn't work. I typed the guest's username/password, it didn't work either.

**What username and password do I enter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you share the printer? There are two methods, one is via *samba* (windows) and the other is via *ipp/cups* (unix). As far as I know, cups doesn't require authentication by default unless you've set it up that way. Samba on the other hand does by default.

I would recommend using cups sharing, ipp works in windows clients as well as any other client and is well supported in Ubuntu. You simply go to your `System > Administration > Printing` and select `Server > Settings`.

[image: printer settings dialog]

You can then visit the ip address of your server in any web browser at port 631 to check you get a connection and access to the printer:

```
`http://192.168.1.20:631/printers`
```

If you do this, your other machine should see this shared printer automatically. Configuration should then be automatic and you should not have any passwords to deal with.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, I didn't know this was possible. :) I was gonna ask how I can find out in what way I shared it, but it doesn't matter. I'll just do it again this way.